# 2 Versions of JQuery on 2 different places conflicting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

So I got my website up but it's not working since I have 2 different JQuery's loaded and when I remove the one line that function just does not work anymore.

```
<link href="social-traffic-pop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.stp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the other one:

```
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="ga.js"></script><script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.tabs.pack.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.pack.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="onload.js"></script>
```

I am wondering on how to fix this and I basically have 0 Javascript experience :/

Thanks!

Comment: Which jQuery version is inside `jquery.min.js`? I suggest you keep the latest version and put it first up, before the other`.js` files. If you get errors check the console and report here which error you get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)